# I am stuck using absolute positioning in my GUI [wxpython]

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

I am have been using absolute positioning for my GUI for a while now but I have added so many things to the GUI that at this point when I change the base layout it can take a couple of hours to realign everything. Now I already know people are going to tell me I should be using sizers for everything but I don't know if that is possible for my use case I have attached an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbUxu.jpg) that shows the base diagram of what I am trying to overlay my controls on to. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwr7O.jpg) is what it looks like when the controls are misaligned over the background schematic. anytime the base image changes I have to manually adjust the absolute positioning of each control so it shows up in the right location. if anyone could explain to me how I can avoid that it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is your schematic a single image file, or is it broken up into sub-images? One way to start would be to lay out your schematic as a bunch of smaller images for each component, calculate (or trial-and-error) the offset between each control and a given image, pull the location of that image once everything's laid out at the end of the `__init__()`, and use wx's CallAfter. You can write a function like

```
def getloc(self, item):
    return self.item.GetScreenPosition()
```

and use it on the images as needed (at the end of `__init__()`, so everything's where it's staying -- unless you're dynamically setting item positions within the frame as the program runs). Then add your controls based on the offsets you want like

```
im1posx, im1posy = self.getloc(img1)
ctrlpos = wx.Point(im1posx+<xoffset>, im1posy+<yoffset>)
ctrl1 = wx.TextControl(<parent>, -1, value="", pos=ctrlpos, size=your_size, style=your_flags)
```

or something like that.

It is a rather tricky situation, though. Why does your base image change so much? And if you're using multiple base images, why don't you separate them into different classes (or class instances) and adjust the control positioning on a per-base-image basis?

If it happens to be the case that you're making this GUI based on a schematic, setting the controls according to the schematic, then changing/updating the schematic down the road... I think it may be worth waiting until the schematic is finalized before bothering laying out the controls at all. Unless you can somehow lay the schematic's components out in a more ordered fashion (in which case, you guessed it, *use sizers*), or wait for a finalized schematic before hard-coding the control positions, wxPython may not be the best GUI framework for this particular application.